# $\frac{\pi}{2}  =\tan^{-1}(\infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Using the result, $\tan^2{\alpha} - A \tan{\alpha} + 1 = 0~$, where A is a constant, prove that the two solutions to this equation (such that $0 \leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$) are complementary (i.e. $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2=\large \frac{\pi}{2}~$)

To solve this equation, suppose the two roots are $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. We can take the product of roots $\Pi\tan{\alpha}: \tan{\alpha_1}\tan{\alpha_2}=1~$, but noting that $\tan(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = \large \frac{\tan{\alpha_1}+\tan{\alpha_2}}{1 - \tan{\alpha_1}\tan{\alpha_2}}~$ from the $\tan$ expansion.

Substituting $\tan{\alpha_1}\tan{\alpha_2}=1~$ into that expansion:

$$\tan(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = \frac{\tan{\alpha_1}+\tan{\alpha_2}}{1 - 1}=\frac{\tan{\alpha_1}+\tan{\alpha_2}}{0}=\infty~$$

Therefore, following on from this, $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = \tan^{-1}(\infty) = \large \frac{\pi}{2}$

**However, is this proof flawed, especially in equating $\large \frac{\tan{\alpha_1}+\tan{\alpha_2}}{0}$ with $\infty~$, and $\tan^{-1}(\infty)$ with $\large \frac{\pi}{2}~$?** Would limits be required for a more proper treatment?

Comment: Yes, you need to take limits, and you need to approach $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from the left (the two-sided limit isn't well-defined even in the extended reals). Alternately, a more abstract fix is to make the tangent take values in something other than the reals (for example the real projective line, which is where it naturally takes values).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to make the question more precise.  After all, for any real number $u$, there are infinitely many $\alpha$ such that $\tan \alpha=u$.  So we will restate the problem.

Suppose that $A>0$ and $A^2-4 \ge 0$.  Then the equation 
$$x^2 -Ax+1=0$$ 
has two (possibly equal) positive solutions, say $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Let $\alpha_i$ be the angle (number) in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ such that $\tan\alpha_i=x_i$.  Show that $\alpha_1 +\alpha_2=\pi/2$.

The addition formula for $\tan$ seems to me not the best way to handle the problem, even though, as Gerry Myerson points out, there is a precise way of interpreting the situation when the denominator is $0$.

It seems to me simpler to note that if $\alpha_i$ are angles in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ we have
$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2=\frac{\pi}{2} \qquad \text{iff}\qquad \tan\alpha_2=\frac{1}{\tan\alpha_1}$$
This follows from primitive properties of right triangles.

So the only thing to verify is that the product of the roots of $x^2-Ax+1=0$ is $1$, and this is clear from the shape of the equation.

**Added comment**: If one takes *great care*, or if one has very good intuition, it is *possible* to handle "$\infty$" without making errors.  Euler (mostly) did it, but we are not all Euler. Improper handling of "$\infty$" is an all too frequent source of student mistakes.  So it is best to do "defensive thinking," and avoid trying to handle "$\infty$" as if it were a number. After all, it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Put $z = \tan(\alpha)$.   Then your equation is 
$$z^2 - Az + 1 = 0.$$
Real roots exist provided that $A^2 - 4 \ge 0$  In this case, the roots are reciprocals.  Your result then follows right away, since tangents of complementary angles are necessarily reciprocals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any need for limits, nor for projective planes. The formula doesn't show $\tan(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$ is infinite, it shows that it doesn't exist, and the argument for which the tangent doesn't exist is $\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your explanation of $\tan(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ not existing was very helpful. :)